# How can I save a boolean value to hide or show a button?

Tags: objective-c, state, game-development

My Question concerns an easy way for a game level selection.
For example: I have two `ViewControllers`. On one `ViewController` I programmed a game code. If I achieve the game goal I will show a hidden button (`UIButton.hidden = NO`) which links me to the other `ViewController` with the next level. So far so good.

But I would love to save this state, so when I close and open the app again, this hidden button should still be available because I already achieved the goal of this level.

I tried using `NSUserDefaults`, but I couldn't figure out how to save a boolean. How can I save an `if/else` state for button trigger?

Comment: And without Xcode (unrelated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but it sounds fairly straightforward:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"buttonVisible"];
BOOL buttonVisible = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"buttonVisible"];
```

Concerning the below discussion. The notification pattern would look something like this:
In the viewController where the necessary goal is achieved:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil];
```

In the viewController where you need to be made aware of the change:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(makeLevelButtonVisible) name:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. But how can I can keep the button not hidden anymore, when the button for the next level trigger is on a different ViewController? Thats what I don't quite understand. thx

Comment: One way would be to use a notification. The notification-pattern is actually particularly well suited to games in my opinion as you quite often want to have several classes react to the same thing. You might for instance want a sound to play, the score to change and an animation occur all on a collision between two sprites...

Comment: Ok. So when I get you right. The Notification-pattern would work for two viewcontroller using the same classes? How would that look like?

Comment: I've added some small examples to the above answer. You would use the notification pattern to make changes during the game, and (if necessary) use the userDefaults if you want to save the state between gaming sessions.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I'm getting there slowly:-) So, I have two ViewControllers. ViewController_1 and ViewController_2. Like you said, I iplemented [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil]; on ViewController_1 and [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(makeLevelButtonVisible) name:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil]; ViewController_2. So it looks something like this:

Comment: ViewController_1.m

if (tapToBegin.text == @"You Win..!") {[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil]; }

ViewController_2.m

nextLevelButton.hidden = yes;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(makeLevelButtonVisible) name:@"nextLevelGoalAchieved" object:nil];

-(void)makeLevelButtonVisible{

nextLevelButton.hidden = yes; }

Comment: so, it would work, when i could save the state on ViewController_1, cause when I swap to ViewController_2 the if statement is obviously gone cause i left the ViewController, so the button will still be hidden. But I'm not sure how to work with nsuserdefault. Cause like you said, i should use the userDefaults. But how do i save the state: if (tapToBegin.text == @"You Win..!")? And even if i would be able to safe that state to enable the nectLevelButtton, wouldn't it be all gone, as soon I delete the app in multitask and reopen?

Comment: It's getting a bit hard to continue this discussion on an abstract level. IF both VCs are alive at the same time and you need VC2 to know about the change, then you'll need the Notification bits. On the other hand, if VC2 is NOT alive OR you want to use the state from a previous session then you'll need to base it on the NSUserDefaults. When setting up the button you will simply have to do a simple if-statement to set the visible property of the button. The NSUserDefaults are stored when you call synchronize. Also: Feel free to mark my answer as useful at any time. ;)

Comment: I'm sure you will! Just try to be as precise as possible when asking the questions. Don't be shy to include code-snippets as it'll make it a lot easier to help in many cases. At the moment I am not sure if you're actually struggling with code or structural problems. - Oh, and thanks for the vote. :)